# Link to full size image in Colorbox

Tags: jquery, colorbox

Is there any way to link to the original image in Colorbox?

I have a hack which works OK, but I want know if there is any other way to do this:

```
<a href="full_size.jpg" title="<a class='cbox_expand' href='full_size.jpg'>Expand</a>">Photo_1</img>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('a.example').colorbox({
  title: function() {
    return $('<a>Expand</a>').attr('href', $(this).attr('href'));
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi Jack, Thanks but how do I implement thiS? Can you give me some advice? My link to the image in colorbox is just a link with some set classes that load the colorbox frame but I'm unsure how I can use your script wit that.... Thanks!

Comment: Add it after the init code where you are setting colorbox options.
Or if you are using the defaults or that came as a option-less plugin (I doubt it), add it to the jquery.colorbox.js, before the last "})". 
Alternatively, you can google "how to link to external jQuery (document).ready" and you'll get plenty of tutorials. Your website definitely must have some JS file, for example, where the init of